# Is there a faster way than "for" to compare values in column to choose the one i want?

Tags: python, pandas

I have these two different columns in a dataframe. I want to iterate and know if column `'Entry_Point'` is a Str then in`Delivery_Point` put the `Client_Num`.

```
df
Client_Num     Entry_Point        Delivery_Point
1                      0
2                      a
3                      3
4                      4
5                      b
6                      c
8                      d
```

It should look like this:

```
Client_Num     Entry_Point        Delivery_Point
1                     10                 10
2                      a                 2
3                      32                32
4                      14                14
5                      b                 5
6                      c                 6
8                      d                 8
```

I already tried doing a for but it takes too long, especially when I have 20k rows.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
   if  type(df.loc[i]['Entry_Point']) == str:
       df.loc[i]['Delivery_Point'] = df.loc[i]['Client_num']
   else:
       df.loc[i]['Delivery_Point'] = df.loc[i]['Entry_Point']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us using pandas `to_numeric`

```
df['New']=pd.to_numeric(df.Entry_Point,errors='coerce').fillna(df.Client_Num)
df
Out[22]: 
   Client_Num Entry_Point  New
0           1           0  0.0
1           2           a  2.0
2           3           3  3.0
3           4           4  4.0
4           5           b  5.0
5           6           c  6.0
6           8           d  8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas column will be imported as a single data type. So the method you apply may not fetch the correct result. I think you want to do the following:

```
df['Delivery_Point'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Client_num if not x.Entry_Point.strip().isnumeric() else x.Entry_Point, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option that might perform even better on very large datasets is to use vectorized numpy functions:

```py
import numpy as np

@np.vectorize
def get_if_str(client_num, entry_point):
    if isinstance(entry_point, str):
        return client_num
    return entry_point

df['Delivery_Point'] = get_if_str(df['Client_Num'], df['Entry_Point'])
```

We can compare the times here:

```py
##slow way
def generic(df):
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if  type(df.loc[i]['Entry_Point']) == str:
            df.loc[i]['Delivery_Point'] = df.loc[i]['Client_Num']
        else:
            df.loc[i]['Delivery_Point'] = df.loc[i]['Entry_Point']

%timeit generic(df)
# 237 ms ± 5.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# Miliseconds

%timeit df['Delivery_Point'] = get_if_int(df['Client_Num'], df['Entry_Point'])

#185 µs ± 1.38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# Microseconds
```

As you can see, considerable gains from using Numpy vectorized functions. More about them can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

**EDIT**

If you actually use the numpy array of the values, you should get an even better performance from the vectorization:

```py
df['Delivery_Point'] = get_if_str(df['Client_Num'].values, df['Entry_Point'].values)
```